# Facebook Business SDK: cannot create an Ad

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, ads, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I cannot create a simple Ad with an external link to a mobile app. I have properly set access, can create a Campaign, an AdSet, load an image, but during an Ad creation I get an error:

> Ads and ad creatives must be associated with a Facebook Page. Try connecting your ad or ad creative to a Page and resubmit your ad.

But I have associated a page! Here is my code:

```
# No problem with these ones
adset = ...
image_hash = '...'
url = 'https://itunes.apple.com/app/96...'
page_id = '25036...'

# Create an Ad Creative
creative = AdCreative()
creative['_parent_id'] = my_ads_acc_id
creative[AdCreative.Field.title] = 'Aivan Test Creative'
creative[AdCreative.Field.body] = 'Aivan Test Ad Creative Body'
creative[AdCreative.Field.actor_id] = page_id
creative[AdCreative.Field.link_url] = url
creative[AdCreative.Field.object_url] = url
creative[AdCreative.Field.object_type] = AdCreative.ObjectType.domain
creative[AdCreative.Field.call_to_action_type] = AdCreative.CallToActionType.use_mobile_app
creative[AdCreative.Field.image_hash] = image_hash

# Create an Ad
ad = Ad()
ad['_parent_id'] = my_ads_acc_id
ad[Ad.Field.name] = 'Aivan Ad'
ad[Ad.Field.adset_id] = adset[AdSet.Field.id]
ad[Ad.Field.creative] = creative
# This line generates an exception:
ad.remote_create(params={
    'status': Ad.Status.paused,
})
```

I have specified the **`actor_id`** field, also I have tried other different code samples, but nothing works well. How can I connect a page?

*Additional info:*

- My app is in development mode. I cannot turn the production mode because it needs a review which needs a completed app.
- I have tried to use `object_story_spec` with `link_data` in it, but it creates other error because it doesn't work in development mode.
- The app and the page are linked with Facebook Business Manager.
- The results is the same if I init the API with app token or system user token: `FacebookAdsApi.init(app_id, app_secret, app_access_token / system_user_token)`. The system user has access to both Ads Account and the Page.

Comment: _“But init doesn't work with access tokens of system users I created in Business Manager”_ - meaning what exactly?

Comment: @CBroe I updated the info. Using a system user token with granted access didn't change anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved the problem a long time ago, and since that time my server app successfully created lots of Facebook ads of both types, for websites and mobile apps. The first step to solve the problem was to understand that these ads types are completely different on Facebook, they need different  settings for Campaign, AdSet & Ad. Here is my code for **mobile ads** creation.

**1)** Create [Campaign object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/). `account_id` must be the ID of your Ad Account.

```
campaign = Campaign()
campaign['_parent_id'] = account_id
campaign[Campaign.Field.name] = 'Some Campaign Name'
campaign[Campaign.Field.objective] = 'APP_INSTALLS'
campaign.remote_create()
campaign_id = str(campaign[Campaign.Field.id])
```

**2)** Create [AdSet object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/).

```
adset = AdSet()
adset['_parent_id'] = account_id
adset.update({
    AdSet.Field.name: 'Some AdSet Name',
    AdSet.Field.campaign_id: campaign_id,
    AdSet.Field.lifetime_budget: budget * 100,
    AdSet.Field.bid_strategy: 'LOWEST_COST_WITHOUT_CAP',
    AdSet.Field.billing_event: AdSet.BillingEvent.link_clicks,
    AdSet.Field.optimization_goal: AdSet.OptimizationGoal.link_clicks,
    AdSet.Field.promoted_object: {
        'object_store_url': app_store_url,
        'application_id': ad_app_id,
    },
    AdSet.Field.targeting: targeting_object,
    AdSet.Field.start_time: '2018-12-01 00:00:00',
    AdSet.Field.end_time: '2018-12-30 23:59:00',
})
adset.remote_create()
adset_id = str(adset[AdSet.Field.id])
```

Note that to create mobile ad, you initially need to register your mobile app as a Facebook app (here you will get `ad_app_id`) and specify links to Apple App Store and Google Play Market. So, the value of `app_store_url` must be equal to one of those links in your Facebook app settings. Unfortunately, app can be registered only manually (if you know how to do it programmatically – write a comment, please).

Also note that `billing_event` and `optimization_goal` are connected with ads type (mobile/web) and with each other, you cannot just choose another one. (But if you know that this is possible, or there are some docs on this topics – let me know.)

`budget` is a money amount in the currency of your Ad Account. You can specify either `lifetime_budget` or something like day_budget, read the docs about it.

**3)** Then, you have to create [AdCreative object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative/) with some other sub objects. Note that some of these lines of code are necessary for FB ad only, others for IG, others for both of them, but together they work well for everything. You can find [description  for all the formats here](https://www.facebook.com/business/ads-guide/image).

```
link_data = AdCreativeLinkData()
link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.name] = main_text
link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.message] = title
link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.link] = app_store_url
link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.image_hash] = image_hash
link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.call_to_action] = {
    'type': 'INSTALL_MOBILE_APP',
    'value': {
        'application': ad_app_id,
        'link': app_store_url,
    },
}

object_story_spec = AdCreativeObjectStorySpec()
object_story_spec[AdCreativeObjectStorySpec.Field.page_id] = page_id
object_story_spec[AdCreativeObjectStorySpec.Field.link_data] = link_data

creative = AdCreative()
creative['_parent_id'] = account_id
creative[AdCreative.Field.object_story_spec] = object_story_spec
creative[AdCreative.Field.title] = main_text
creative[AdCreative.Field.body] = title
creative[AdCreative.Field.actor_id] = page_id
creative[AdCreative.Field.link_url] = app_store_url
creative[AdCreative.Field.image_hash] = image_hash
```

To upload an image and get `image_hash`, check out [this doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image/). The `page_id` must be an ID of the page which name and logo will be shown as the author of the ad.

You must note that the user, who creates the ad, must have an access to this page, to the mobile app registered on FB (`ad_app_id`), and to the Ad Account (`account_id`). In my server application I use [Facebook system users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/businessmanager/systemuser/) for all the work with API.

**4)** And finally, create the [Ad object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/) itself:

```
ad = Ad()
ad['_parent_id'] = account_id
ad[Ad.Field.name] = 'Some Ad Name'
ad[Ad.Field.adset_id] = adset_id
ad[Ad.Field.creative] = creative
ad.remote_create(params={
    'status': Ad.Status.active,
})
ad_id = str(ad[Ad.Field.id])
```

That's all!

Comment: Hi AivanF, how can you with api calls assign to your system users tha page ? We have stack on steep 3 (we can add the page manually to the user) but how to add it with api all ?

Comment: @OscarJofre We found no way to accomplish this, so we assigned all the pages manually.

Comment: the other way arround could be to add the system user to that page ? But there should be a way.

Comment: I found how to do it. With the token of the admin system user (you can get it from bussines manager on "generate new identifier") and calling $response = $fb->post(
    '/123146749086177/assigned_users',
    array (
      'user' => '100022818247829',
      'tasks' => '['ADVERTISE', 'ANALYZE']'
    ),
    '{access-token}'
  );

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone will need to use or just want to see the difference when creating FB/IG ads for websites, it is a little bit simpler. So, here is my code for **website ads** creation.

**1)** Create [Campaign object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign-group/). Notice that website ads has a different `objective`. `account_id` must be the ID of your Ad Account.

```
campaign = Campaign()
campaign['_parent_id'] = account_id
campaign[Campaign.Field.name] = 'Some Campaign Name'
campaign[Campaign.Field.objective] = 'LINK_CLICKS'
campaign.remote_create()
campaign_id = str(campaign[Campaign.Field.id])
```

**2)** Create [AdSet object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign/). Note that `billing_event` and `optimization_goal` are connected with ads type (mobile/web) and with each other. Also, here you don't need to specify `promoted_object` in the AdSet.

```
adset = AdSet()
adset['_parent_id'] = account_id
adset.update({
    AdSet.Field.name: 'Some AdSet Name',
    AdSet.Field.campaign_id: campaign_id,
    AdSet.Field.lifetime_budget: budget * 100,
    AdSet.Field.bid_strategy: 'LOWEST_COST_WITHOUT_CAP',
    AdSet.Field.billing_event: AdSet.BillingEvent.impressions,
    AdSet.Field.optimization_goal: AdSet.OptimizationGoal.reach,
    AdSet.Field.targeting: targeting_object,
    AdSet.Field.start_time: '2018-12-01 00:00:00',
    AdSet.Field.end_time: '2018-12-30 23:59:00',
})
adset.remote_create()
adset_id = str(adset[AdSet.Field.id])
```

<sub>Rules for budget are the same: `budget` is a money amount in the currency of your Ad Account. You can specify either `lifetime_budget` or something like day_budget, read the docs about it.</sub>

**3)** Then, you have to create [AdCreative object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-creative/) with some other sub objects. You can find [description  for all the formats here](https://www.facebook.com/business/ads-guide/image).

```
link_data = AdCreativeLinkData()
link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.name] = main_text
link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.message] = title
link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.link] = website_url
link_data[AdCreativeLinkData.Field.image_hash] = image_hash

object_story_spec = AdCreativeObjectStorySpec()
object_story_spec[AdCreativeObjectStorySpec.Field.page_id] = page_id
object_story_spec[AdCreativeObjectStorySpec.Field.link_data] = link_data

creative = AdCreative()
creative['_parent_id'] = account_id
creative[AdCreative.Field.object_story_spec] = object_story_spec
creative[AdCreative.Field.title] = main_text
creative[AdCreative.Field.body] = title
creative[AdCreative.Field.actor_id] = page_id
creative[AdCreative.Field.link_url] = website_url
creative[AdCreative.Field.object_type] = AdCreative.ObjectType.domain
creative[AdCreative.Field.image_hash] = image_hash
```

<sub>To upload an image and get `image_hash`, check out [this doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image/). The `page_id` must be an ID of the page which name and logo will be shown as the author of the ad. Note that the user, who creates the ad, must have an access to this page, to the mobile app registered on FB (`ad_app_id`), and to the Ad Account (`account_id`).</sub>

**4)** And finally, create the [Ad object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/) itself:

```
ad = Ad()
ad['_parent_id'] = account_id
ad[Ad.Field.name] = 'Some Ad Name'
ad[Ad.Field.adset_id] = adset_id
ad[Ad.Field.creative] = creative
ad.remote_create(params={
    'status': Ad.Status.active,
})
ad_id = str(ad[Ad.Field.id])
```

As you can see, to promote websites you don't need to register them on Facebook (in contrast to mobile ads).

Comment: Hi, @AivanF. Thanks for this, however, you mentioned that you did all this whilst your app was in development mode? Is that your app using the Marketing API too?

The reason I ask is that when trying to create an AdCreative I get the error cannot create ad creative in development mode... 

Maybe it has something to do with the system user your using or???

Comment: @philkills Hi! To be honest, I don't already remember, but if you need this info, feel free to write me [in PM on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100010912653374), I'll look the app settings.